# Image processing with z transform

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, transform

I am implementing the z transformation and I am using the built-in function `ztrans` in Matlab. Now i give

```
    x=imread('lena512.bmp');
    x=im2double(x);
    z=ztrans(x);
```

where `x` contains the pixel values of an image and `ztrans(x)` should apply z-transformation. But i am getting an error like this

```
    ??? Undefined function or method 'ztrans' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

How can I use the function and apply z transformation on images?

Comment: `ztrans` is for symbolic computations, whereas you're feeding a numeric matrix. That seems to be the problem

Answer (score -2):

Z = zscore(X) returns the z-score for each element of X such that **columns** of X are centered to have mean 0 and scaled to have standard deviation 1. Z is the same size as X.

so in order to do what you wanted you should use this instead

```
x= zscore(x)
imshow(x,[])
```

keep in mind that this will give you some weird results as this is done for each column, to create a global transformation you should do the following

```
[m,n]= size(x)
x= zscore(x(:)) 
x = reshape(x,m,n)
imshow(x,[])
```

enjoy
enjoy

Comment: The question is about the z-transform. z-score is something completely different.